# Semantria Integration with DB

Tags: analytics, semantics, semantic-web, semantic-ui, semantic-analysis

I need to know, has someone integrated any DB to Semantria, and get output to any DB or excel or text file ?

I have tried to explore semantria via excel and API , but integration does not work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of integration you're looking for.
I have already done many integrations with different storages including indexing services and RDBMS solutions.
Unfortunately there are no ready-to-use components available on the market, so you will need to build integration by your own.
Semantria offers SDK (https://github.com/Semantria/semantria-sdk) for all modern languages, you will need to build a logic that will get analysis results and will save them to a certain storage.
Can you please explain what storage do you use and what Semantria output you're interested in?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks George.
Well at the moment, we are just focusing on pulling the data from DB (take for instance mySQL, or Oracle), and output should again go back to same DB, i will take care of transformation needed in o/p.

Now where I am stuck, is the place where I can set up a link between DB and semantria, how will these SDK help, never worked on something like this.
A brief on this will surely be of great help